# Log4j не видит properties файл

Tags: java, log4j

У меня задача организовать вывод в консоль объектов при добавлении в базу:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ByTheDayController.class);

Queue<Proposal> proposals = ...;

log.info(proposals.peek());

channelToDatabase.ingection(proposals.poll());
```

Я добавил `log4j.properties` :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Но при попытке запуска получаю:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ru.pravvich.timing.ByTheDayController).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Но когда при старте я вызываю:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout("%m%n")));
```

То все работает, но я хочу что-бы `PatternLayout` загружался из файла. Помогите пожалуйста это поправить. Спасибо.

Comment: сначала считываешь проперти с конфига `Properties p = new Properties(); load....`, потом `BasicConfigurator.configure(p)`, а если нужен только паттерн, то получаешь значение `p.get("log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern")` и вставляешь вместо своего хардкода

Comment: Куда Вы добавили `log4j.properties`? Как запускаете java?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor BasicConfigurator.configure(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout(строку из проретри файла)). Правильно?

Comment: @Павел да , ты прав

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для начала необходимо считывать проперти с конфига

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("log4j.properties");
prop.load(input);


// получаем значение параметра нужного 
String pattern = prop.getProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern");

// устанавливаем наше значение 

BasicConfigurator.configure(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout(pattern)));
```